# MakeLine with aggregate based on line id

Tags: spatialite

I want to create a line between points 104 and 74. This works :

```
select 1 as axe, make_line(p1.geometry, p2.geometry) as geometry 
from MR200_amers_plan p1, MR200_amers_plan p2 
where p1.matricule = 104 and p2.matricule = 74
```

Now I can't get the same result with the aggregate function. I added a column ligne holding the line number, and tried:

```
select p.ligne, make_line(p.geometry) as geometry from 
(select ligne, geometry from MR200_amers_plan where matricule 
in ('104', '74') order by gid DESC) as p group by p.ligne
```

I can't figure out the reason even according to http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_MakeLine.html or http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p5

Comment: Can you explain the problem ? What do you mean with "Now I can't get the same result " ?

Comment: I can't create/draw the line. Nothing happens

Comment: Is the query "select ligne, geometry from MR200_amers_plan where matricule 
in ('104', '74') order by gid DESC" is devolving some rows ?

Comment: I can't understand 'devolving'. If it means : is the result (of query) correct ? I say yes : I get 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `MakeLine(Collect(p.geometry))`

Comment: it does not work. Sorry.

Comment: ... and `GUnion(p.geometry)`? The Clou is that you need to use some aggregate function.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is why GROUP BY is used as mentionned in gaia documentation. Makeline is a an aggregate function.